# Document.getelementByID undefined error

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure why I am getting.may be there is some issue with this keyword that is used in the code .when I just alert with only one input text it shows the output

> TypeError: document is undefined newhtml.html:30:16

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
        function calcAvg(val)
        {

            var x=document.getElementById(val.id).value 
            var form=val.form;
            var form_name=form.name;
            var document=form_name.document;
            var value=val.value;
            var name=val.name;
            alert(form.name +' '+document );
            var valueOne    = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            var valueTwo    = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
            var valueThree  = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
            var valueFour   = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
            var valueFive   = document.getElementById('txt5').value;
                        performCalc(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour, valueFive);
        }

        function performCalc(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour, valueFive) 
        {
            var calcResult = parseInt(valueOne) + parseInt(valueTwo) + parseInt(valueThree) + parseInt(valueFour) + parseInt(valueFive);
            var averageResult = calcResult / 5;
            return averageResult;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' id='txt1' name='txt1' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)'/>
        <input type='text' id='txt2' name='txt2' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)'/>
    <input type='text' id='txt3' name='txt3' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)'/>
    <input type='text' id='txt4' name='txt4' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)'/>
    <input type='text' id='txt5' name='txt5' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)'/>
    <input type='text' id='averageResult' name='averageResult' value='0' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4...seriously, was it *that hard* to tell us which line is line 30? Esp. as line 30 appears to be `}`?

Comment: Use `this.id` for get id of input

Comment: FWIW, `var x=document.getElementById(val.id).value` is a really long way to write `var x = val.value`, since what you're passing in *is* what you get back from `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

This line makes no sense:

```
var document=form_name.document;
```

Remove it.

You also have a bunch of other lines at the beginning of that function that seem to serve no purpose and which cause errors as well.

You also aren't *using* the return value from your `performCalc` function.

Here's a version with those things removed and which assigns the result of `performCalc` to the `averageResult` element:

```js
function calcAvg(val) {

  var valueOne = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var valueTwo = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
  var valueThree = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
  var valueFour = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
  var valueFive = document.getElementById('txt5').value;
  document.getElementById("averageResult").value = performCalc(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour, valueFive);
}

function performCalc(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour, valueFive) {
  var calcResult = parseInt(valueOne) + parseInt(valueTwo) + parseInt(valueThree) + parseInt(valueFour) + parseInt(valueFive);
  var averageResult = calcResult / 5;
  return averageResult;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txt1' name='txt1' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)' />
<input type='text' id='txt2' name='txt2' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)' />
<input type='text' id='txt3' name='txt3' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)' />
<input type='text' id='txt4' name='txt4' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)' />
<input type='text' id='txt5' name='txt5' value=0 onchange='calcAvg(this)' />
<input type='text' id='averageResult' name='averageResult' value='0' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `this.id` for get id for each input
Ex:

and clean `val` from function and `val.id`

```
function calcAvg(val)
        {

            var x=document.getElementById(val.id).value 
            var form=val.form;
            var form_name=form.name;
            var document=form_name.document;
            var value=val.value;
            var name=val.name;
            alert(form.name +' '+document );
            var valueOne    = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            var valueTwo    = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
            var valueThree  = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
            var valueFour   = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
            var valueFive   = document.getElementById('txt5').value;
                        performCalc(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour, valueFive);
        }
```